# Files saved by carrierwave is being gotten visible to users not logged in

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx, file-upload, carrierwave

## Current Detail

#### [Env]

nginx puma mysql
Rails == 5.1.5

I mounted carrierwave to upload pictures and files in a post.

#### [Case]

Users not logged in type the file URL in browser, then they can access and view the file.

#### [Ideal]

Only users logged in is accessible to the file.

The file path is "uploads/post/images/1234(post_id)/sample.png".
So far, I locate uploads directory under public, app/assets/, and root directory in vain.

Any answers or suggestions are appreciated.

---

## Source

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/index'
  get 'users/show'
  get 'posts/index'

  devise_for :users, module: :users
  resources :users, :only => [:index, :show]

  get "/" => "posts#index"
  get "posts/like_ranking" => "posts#like_rank"
  get "posts/post_count_ranking" => "posts#post_count"
  get "posts/tags_search" => "posts#tags_search"
  get "posts/new" => "posts#new"
  get "posts/:id/reply" => "posts#new"
  post "posts/create" => "posts#create"
  get "posts/:id" => "posts#show"
  get "posts/:id/edit" => "posts#edit"
  post "posts/:id/update" => "posts#update"
  post "posts/:id/destroy" => "posts#destroy"

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag

  get "users/:id/likes" => "users#likes"
  get "users/:id/reply" => "users#reply"

  resources :posts, only: %w(index)

  resources :posts, shallow: true do
    resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

"

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-secure-upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All assets under the `public` folder is served by `nginx`. In order to make it available for logged users you can first upload files to other directory than `public` and create action which serve files by Rails app from that directory and check if users logged before serving.